# Running a loop through JSON dictionary with survey questions SWIFT

Tags: json, swift, loops

So here is my code to iterate through my JSON dictionary and on my console it prints each question and not the question title.

```
for x in r {
    if(x.0.containsString("Question")){
        print(x.1)
        self.questionLabel.text = (x.1) as! String  
    } else if (x.0.containsString("Ladder")) {
        print(x.1)
    }
}
```

I want to be able to control the loop by pressing a NEXT button before it will iterate onto next question. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you give some information about your dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries are a SequenceType which sit on top of something called generators. Generators facilitate looping by having a method called next(). By calling next() you get access to the next item in the Sequence. Something along the following lines should get you most of the way towards what you're after:

```
let dict = ["Question":"What is the population of ...",
            "Ladder" : "Something else I guess?"]

var generator = dict.generate()

func nextQuestion() -> String? {
    if let pair = generator.next() {
        if pair.0.containsString("Question") {
            return pair.1
        }

        // recusively calls itself until if finds another question 
        // or runs out of entries
        return nextQuestion()
    }

    // no more entries in the dictionary
    return nil
}

print(nextQuestion()) // prints: Optional("What is the population of ...")
print(nextQuestion()) // prints: nil
```

So basically, nextQuestion() will hunt through the generator until it finds the next question and returns it. It will either run out of things to search and so return nil, or it will find the next question and return that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you can give some information about how your dictionary is built I could provide a better answer, but this is what I can give you with the code you provided. Hope it helps

```
let trackingNumber: Int = 0
let arrayWithDictionary = NSArray() //Assuming you have a array with dictionaries

func getNextQuestion(){

let question = arrayWithDictionary[trackingNumber].valueForKey("Question") as! String
let ladder = arrayWithDictionary[trackingNumber].valueForKey("ladder") as! String

 self.questionLabel.text = question
trackingNumber += 1
}
```

Connect your "next question" button and call 'getNextQuestion()' to get the next question.

```
@IBAction func nextButton(sender: UIButton){
    getNextQuestion() 
}
```